# Insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' when attaching a database

Tags: sql-server, restore

There is a website which uses an MSSQL database, from which the *master.mdf* and *master.ldf* files were copied and sent to me, so I can create a local copy of that database. I put these files in a directory, and I referenced them in this create database statement. I am attempting to create a new database that does not yet exist for me locally, using those files.

I've been struggling to import a database backup I have been given into my local SQL Server environment. In SQL Server Management Studio (v18.6) I am attempting to run the following query:

```
Create database mydbname
On
(Filename='D:\some\path\master.mdf'),
(Filename='D:\some\path\mastlog.ldf')
For attach;
```

(These files are not large, 4mb and 2mb respectively).

This is the error message I am getting:

> Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Could not open new database
> 'mydbname'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>
> Msg 701, Level 17, State 192,
> Line 1 There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default'
> to run this query.

I have 32GB of RAM, my "Maximum Server Memory" setting is 16000. (Windows 10 Pro, version 20H2).

If I open the properties dialog of Management > Resource Governor > Resource Pools > System Resource Pools > default, the settings are as follows:

- Workload groups for resource pool: Memory Grant % = 25
- External resource pools: Maximum Memory % = 50

I tried various different values here to no effect. Looking around for others who have reported this error message hasn't turned up anything very helpful. Any ideas?

```
SELECT @@VERSION
    
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)
Nov  6 2020 16:50:01 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19042: )
```

These were the only two files provided to me. The database itself is not called "master", at least the website that references it does not refer to that name. Should it matter what the content of the database is? I'm more familiar with PostgreSQL, where the name of the dump file doesn't have to match the name of the DB you are restoring to. This is perhaps complicated by the fact that the files I have were exported from a Linux environment.

```
DBCC checkprimaryfile(N'D:\some\path\master.mdf', 2)
```

The database name is reported as "master" according to that command.

Comment: The master database is a system database in SQL Server. IT is the "root" database, so to speak. It would be strange to distribute a SQL Server database named "master". So either the files you have is indeed this system database and hence SQL Server complains. Or the database was really named something different, but they renamed the files to master (i.e., the contents isn't that of the system database) and SQL Server is still confused (by the file names).

Comment: @FrankieD, I think it is likely you were provided the wrong files unless all the user objects are stored in the master system database. View the file header via the SSMS attach database wizard or with this undocumented command: `DBCC checkprimaryfile(N'D:\some\path\master.mdf', 2)`. This will show the source database name.

Comment: @DanGuzman the database name is reported as "master" according to that command. I'm not sure what the user objects are in the context of MSSQL, are they necessary to restore a database? In other DB systems, you don't need to export any DB users necessarily, just the table structure and data for the website. Not sure if this is in any way comparable, I'm new to the admin side for MSSQL.

Comment: @FrankieD, they gave you the master system database files. Those files cannot be attached. User-defined database objects (tables, views, etc.) are rarely stored the master so I suggest you reach out to them to ensure they gave you the right files before going down a rabbit hole. In SQL Server ,the master database generally contains server-level objects like logins (used for instance authentication) which map to database users (used for authorization).

Comment: @FrankieD, ask them to send you a database backup of the user database rather than database files.